# SQL Query give results from wrong table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Its very strange. I do a `SQL` query which works totally fine when he found entries that match. But I tested it with no database entries to show the user "NOTHING TO SHOW" but then it gives me back the complete user row which is in another table and I don't can figure out why this is happening.

my connection

```
try 
   {   $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$_MYSQL['host']};
       dbname={$_MYSQL['database']}", $_MYSQL['user'], $_MYSQL['pass'], [     PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",     PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true   ]); 
      } 
catch (PDOException $e) {   exit($e->getMessage()); 
}
```

my code

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT id, oname, datum, prov FROM completed_tasks WHERE user_id =" .$db->quote($user['id']));
    
    if ($sql->rowCount() != 0) {
         $row = $sql->fetchAll();
     }
```

When in `completed_task` are entries with the `user_id` it works like expected. When there is nothing to match in table `completed_tasks` it gives me the complete user row from a totally different table `users`. So how can this happen?

Comment: What id your `$sql` object - is it native PDO, or maybe something else?

Comment: Are the tables related, for instance one if a view of the other, of there is a stored procedure that ties them together. Also, use parameterized queries to prevent sql injection, even if you're only having rusted sources entering info. This type of uery handles all of the things needed to make user your sql is clean, including the proper quotes.

Comment: use **prepared statements with parameters**, this helps not only against **sql injection** , and also test your qiery i believe that you dn't know what result you get from $db->quote($user['id'])

Comment: I dont know what you mean with related? When a user login i create a $user variable that stores the whole user. And i grab info from another table in the same database.

Comment: @nbk i also checked what $db->quote($user['id']) its the correct user id so im am a little helpless right now :)

Comment: in such cases, besides using prepared statements, is to check the general log of the server and check what exactly reaches the server, like isaid before, i don't thing that you have what you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code you provided seems to be correct.

It might be, that `$row` variable is also used somewhere else in your code - maybe before of after snippet you provided.  And since this particular query has no rows in the result, content of `$row` remains the same - so it might contain result from the previous query. It might also be, that it will be overwritten later on.

Comment: that was it :D thank you so much. I had the same variable name in a different file.